# I am having trouble in finding a regex

Tags: regex

I need a regex pattern in which i want to allow first two as alphabets(lowercase and uppercase both are accepted) and rest will be numbers but want to restrict it to 8 digits only.

So overall a text field has max length of 10 in which first two will be alphabets and rest will be digits.

I have tried with this

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{2}+[0-9]{8}$/
```

but not working.

Comment: There is a superfluous '+' in your regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{0,8}$
```

To understand how to work with regex look here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)